# Matlab: How to sum power nth of elements of a matrix rowise or column wise?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

Is there any way except using for loop (a vertorized format which is faster) to compute the sum of power nth of elements of a matrix rowise or column wise?

Comment: Post your loop.  "sum of power of nth elements" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific command for that, but a work around which does not require a for-loop would be as below:

For instance if `n=3`, i.e. third power of matrix elements:

For columnwise summation:

```
a=[1 2;3 4];

m = sum(a.*a.*a,1)
```

For rowise summation:

```
a=[1 2;3 4];

m = sum(a.*a.*a,2)
```

Comment: Judging from the time difference between you asking this question and your answer, I am feeling that you are attempting to make this a Q & A question where you are answering your own posed question.  Unfortunately what you are asking and your answer is low quality.  For instance, many MATLAB users know about element-wise power operations (i.e. `.^`). This question and answer doesn't offer value to StackOverflow I'm afraid.  Specifically, in your case why don't you just do `a.^3` instead of `a.*a.*a`?  For any value of `n`, it would simply `a.^n` no?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [element-wise power operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html).

EDIT: Corrected the sum of the columns (thanks @LuisMendo).

Sum the columns:

```
n = 3; % nth power
res = sum(mat .^ n, 1)
```

Sum the rows:

```
n = 3; % nth power
res = sum(mat .^ n, 2)
```

Comment: _Sum the columns_ is `res = sum(mat .^ n, 1)`, not `res = sum(mat .^ n)`. `mat` might have a single row

Comment: @LuisMendo Reminds me of a certain quote made by a certain individual [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) ;).

Comment: @rayryeng Indeed! :-)